# How can user add items "on the fly" to a LOV in APEX

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I created a dynamic LOV in APEX consisting of all the unique values in a column.
Ex. The column is named "Title" and I wanted the user to be able to choose from the titles that are currently in this column. This works fine. But I also want the user to be able to add a value to the list if he decides he needs a new value other than the ones which are already in that column. How do I do this in Apex?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your page item type is Pop up LOV, you could probably do it by changing the **Input Field** under Settings to **'Enterable, show and store return value'** and have the LOV self reference the table.

You could also do it by making the page item **auto-complete** and have the LOV self reference the table. You could set the lazy loading to Yes, if the list is too big, makes the page load faster.

Hope this helps.